# What if query of transaction raise exception?

Tags: android, sqlite, try-catch, android-sqlite

What happens if exception happens during transaction? `db.endTransaction()` will get called, but any of the query from transaction will performed? Or all will be cancelled?

```
try {
    db.beginTransaction();
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: In case of an exception you'd want to roll back the transaction. In that case all writes should be rolled back or cancelled.

Comment: It really depends what these commands do! Assuming db.setTransactionSuccessful() is the point where commits is executed, and only after that data will be stored, usually inside the catch block you should have something like db.setTransactionFail(), that will executed a rollback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of [transactions](http://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html) is to ensure that

> all changes within a single transaction in SQLite either occur completely or not at all, even if the act of writing the change out to the disk is interrupted by
>
> - a program crash,
> - an operating system crash, or
> - a power failure.

The Android [`beginTransaction()` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction()) says:

> When the … transaction is ended all of the work done in that transaction … will be committed or rolled back. The changes will be rolled back if any transaction is ended without being marked as clean (by calling setTransactionSuccessful). Otherwise they will be committed.